# Debug Assertion Failed when reset item CComboBox MFC/C++

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

[image: Error]

`GetDataSourceList()` function is called from `OnInitDialog()` fucntion.
`DataSourceConfigPage` class is inherited from `CPropertyPage` class
In `GetDataSourceList()` function , I need to clear all items in combobox
so I used function `ResetContent()` but after running program, it showed debug assertion failed as on image.

Please help me check if where is problem.

Comment: You can click retry and look at what is failing in the actual assertion.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the m_cb... variable you are using, doesn't point to an existing window. m_hWnd is NULL!

So you get an ASSERT.